# Limit of the function $exp$ when $z→-∞$.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, exponential-function

Let us define a function $exp:C→C$ by the assignment $exp(z)=$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z^n/n!)$, where $z∈C$. Now it is clear that $exp$ is a holomorphic function, and hence continuous. Also it is clear from the definition of $exp$ that $exp(z)→∞ $ when $z→∞ $. Now how can I find the limit of $exp(z)$ when $z→-∞ $. The limit is seem to be zero, but how can I find(or prove) it from the definition given above. For $z→∞ $ we can easily determined its limit from the definition. But I have problem with the limit when $z→-∞$. Please help me to understand this.

Comment: Derive the differential equation for the exponential function, then prove that $\exp(-z)\exp(z)=1$ by differentiation.

Comment: This is all fine if the limit is taken along the real axis, but false for other trajectories.

Comment: @pedrotamaroff $|e^z|=|e^x e^{iy}|=e^x\to 0$ as $x\to -\infty$.  So, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @MarkViola OK, that is not what I was thinking the OP meant by $f(z)\to \infty$. But I guess it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show that $\exp(z+w)=\exp(z)\exp(w)$ using multiplication of series and the binomial theorem. Then $\exp(z)\exp(-z)=1$, from which you get the statements for your limits (assuming, of course, that your limits only go through real numbers).